# jMeter hangs on scanner read

Tags: java, memcached, jmeter

I am trying to test my memcached installation using jMeter (we are using jMeter for other functional tests, so using it for memcached seems like the best option). I am using the TelnetClient (`org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetClient`) to connect to memcached and fire a get command:

```
get somekey
```

I can connect, but when I try to read the response, jMeter hangs and needs to be restarted. Here is my code (where memcached_server is the IP for my server):

```
try 
{
   TelnetClient telnet = new TelnetClient();
   telnet.connect("memcached_server", 11211);

   PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(telnet.getOutputStream()), true);
   String command = "get 2f605845757870234d94ae14ca83c660";
   pw.println("get 2f605845757870234d94ae14ca83c660");

   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(telnet.getInputStream()));

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(br);

    System.out.println("Hello stackoverflow!!!!");      
if(scan.hasNext())
    System.out.println("It does have a next: " + scan.toString());
else
    System.out.println("It does NOT have a next");

    String output = "";         
while (scan.hasNext()) {
    String line = scan.nextLine();
        output += line;
        if (line.matches("^END.*$")) 
       break;

    }
    System.out.println("Output: " + output);
telnet.disconnect();

} 
catch(Exception e)
{
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I can run this code in Eclipse and it works fine. In jMeter I am using a BeanShell PostProcessor (some tests run before this memcached test), every time I run it, the program gets stuck in the

```
scan.hasNext()
```

line. It just hangs forever until I kill the process. I have also tried using the utilities in org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils like the toString(input stream) methods and I get the exact same behavior.

Any ideas?

Comment: It could be the scannere recaptured input.

Comment: the weird thing is that it works perfectly fine on Eclipse, this is only an issue in jMeter

Comment: I actually ended up using spymemcached library. I used that library and created my own JAR and I added it as a library to jMeter, that worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you put this code in a Post Processor and not in a Sampler ?

This seems strange.

Also you could try using JSR223 +Groovy which could give you the opportunity to debug the script.